# How to refer in English to the Spanish "consonante" and "asonante" rhymes?

Tags: terminology, poetry

Verses in Spanish language can have two types of rhyme:

- *Consonante* rhyme, in which every sound from the stressed syllable to the end are the same.
- *Asonante* rhyme, in which every vowel sound from the stressed syllable to the end are the same.

A typical example of *consonante* rhyme would be *coche/noche* (somewhat similar to English rhyme *light/night*), whereas an *asonante* rhyme would be *noche/doce* where the vowel sounds *o/e* match but not so the consonant sound *ch/c* (it may be similar to trying to rhyme *light* with *mind*).

I have seen that in English you can talk about *[assonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance)* (or *vowel harmony*) and *[consonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance)*, but it seems to me that those terms do not refer to exactly the same idea as shown above.

So, what is the proper way to refer to the Spanish *consonante* and *asonante* rhymes in English? Or should I just write *asonante rhyme*? Would that be understood provided the right context?

Comment: Since such rhyming is not used in English-language poetry, I guess he question would be how to discuss Spanish poetry in English?  I would guess, just use the Spanish words.  But (as with all technical words) explain them unless you are confident your listeners know them.

Comment: @GEdgar: such rhyming is definitely used in English-language poetry.  In *"A penny for a spool of thread,
A penny for a needle,
That's the way the money goes,
Pop! Goes the weasel,"* the rhyme between *needle* and *weasel* is clearly an *asonante* rhyme. But we don't put *asonante* rhymes in a separate class from other near-rhymes (probably because we have two to three times as many vowels as Spanish).

Answer (score 4):

According to [A GLOSSARY OF RHYMES](http://www.public.asu.edu/~aarios/formsofverse/furtherreading/page2.html), you can have a **perfect rhyme** (**true**, **end**), which seems similar to the Spanish *consonante* (all the sounds rhyme perfectly), or you can have an **imperfect rhyme** (**slant**, **half**, **oblique** etc), which seems to have a broader sense than the Spanish *asonante* (only select sounds rhyme, but these do not have to be vowels).